# How to get the multiple drop down values from checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

On click save button.

We have Domain `Doctor` and based on domain we have `Modules` like `Doctor Add/View, Doctor/Adddoctor` checkbox. Inside Module Doctor/Adddoctor checkbox we having some dropdown list.In case we select some Module then corresponding drop down list value should be send.

But in our code it getting all the drop down vale with or without choosing the check box value. Only checked module drop down value is required.

```
@model MedeilMVC_CLOUD.Models.UserView
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedDomainValue(DomainID) {
        var adminID = jQuery('[id$=hdnAdminID]').val();
        var roleID = $("#RoleID").val();
        var domainID = $("#DomainID").val();
        //$("#Doamin").remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("BindDomainUserAccess")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { RoleID: roleID, DomainID: domainID, AdminID: adminID },
            success: function (data) {
                var html = '';

                $.each(data.DomainUserViews, function (index, item) {

                    html += '<li class="dd-item"><a href="#">' + "<input type='checkbox' id='" + item.DomainID + "' name='DomainUserViews' class='DomainUserViews' />" + " " + item.DomainName + '</a>'

                    html += '<ul id="tree" class="dd-list">'

                    $.each(data.ModuleUserViews, function (index, item) {
                        if (item.ParentModuleID == -1) {

                            item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName
                        }
                        else {
                            item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName + " / " + item.Url
                        }

                        html += '<li class="dd-item"><a href="#">' + "<input type='checkbox' id='" + item.ModuleID + "' name='ModuleUserViews' class='ModuleUserViews' />" + " " + item.ModuleName + '<br />' + '</a>'
                            + '<select class="select2-arrow permission" id="'+ item.ModuleID +'" name="Permission" style="width: 55% !important; border: 1px solid #0c0b0b4f;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">'
                            + '<option value="F">All Permissions</option>'
                            + '<option value="P">Add/Update Only</option>'
                            + '<option value="R">Read Only</option>'
                            + '</select>'
                            + '<br />'
                            + '<select class="select2-arrow" id="ApprovalTo" name="ApprovalTo" style="width: 80% !important; border: 1px solid #0c0b0b4f;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">'
                            + '<option Value="-1" Text="IntialApproval">Initial Approval Option1</option>'
                            + '</select>'
                            + '<br />'
                            + '<select class="select2-arrow" id="InitialApproval2" name="InitialApproval2" style="width: 80% !important; border: 1px solid #0c0b0b4f;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">'
                            + '<option Value="-1" Text="IntialApproval2">Initial Approval Option2</option>'
                            + '</select>'
                            + '<br />'
                            + '<select class="select2-arrow" id="InitialApproval3" name="InitialApproval3" style="width: 80% !important; border: 1px solid #0c0b0b4f;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">'
                            + '<option Value="-1" Text="IntialApproval3">Initial Approval Option3</option>'
                            + '</select>'
                            + '<br />'
                            + '<select class="select2-arrow" id="FinalApproval" name="FinalApproval" style="width: 80% !important; border: 1px solid #0c0b0b4f;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">'
                            + '<option Value="-1" Text="FinalApproval">Final Approval Option1</option>'
                            + '</select>'
                            + '<br />'
                            + '<select class="select2-arrow" id="FinalApproval2" name="FinalApproval2" style="width: 80% !important; border: 1px solid #0c0b0b4f;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">'
                            + '<option Value="-1" Text="FinalApproval2">Final Approval Option2</option>'
                            + '</select>'
                            + '<br />'
                            + '<select class="select2-arrow" id="FinalApproval3" name="FinalApproval3" style="width: 80% !important; border: 1px solid #0c0b0b4f;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;">'
                            + '<option Value="-1" Text="FinalApproval3">Final Approval Option3</option>'
                            + '</select>'
                            + '</li>'

                    });

                    html += '</ul></li>'
                });

                if (html != '') {
                    html = '<ul id="tree" class="dd-list">' + html + '</ul>'
                }

                $('.dd-list').html(html);

            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="col-lg-12" id="Doamin">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="dd tree" id="nestable" style="background: #eceff4; padding: 6px;">
                <ul id="tree" class="dd-list"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On Submit button Click Function:

```
<input type="submit" name="actionType" id="btnSubmit" onclick="AssignUserAccess()" value="Save" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
```

Onclick Save Function:

```
function AssignUserAccess() {
            //DomainUserViews Checked Count
            var $checked = $('.dd-list').find('.DomainUserViews:checked');
            var domainIDS = [];
            $checked.each(function (index) { domainIDS.push($(this).attr("id")); })

            //ModuleUserViews Checked Count
            var $Modulechecked = $('.dd-list').find('.ModuleUserViews:checked');
            var ids = [];
            $Modulechecked.each(function (index) { ids.push($(this).attr("id")); })

            var domainID = $("#DomainID").val();
            var adminID = $("#hdnAdminID").val();
            var roleID = $("#RoleID").val();


            var permission = [];

            permission = $('select.permission').map(function () {
                return $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            }).toArray();

            alert(permission);


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("UserDomains")',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data: { Domains: domainIDS, Modules: ids, DomainID: domainID, AdminID: adminID, RoleID: roleID, Permission: permission },
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {

                    }
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
                }
            });

        }
```

`var permission = [];` Array  our code it getting all the drop down vale with or without choosing the check box value.

Only checked Module Checkbox drop down value is required.

Below I attached output screen:

[image: Output]

`Doctor Add/view` Unchecked but dropdown value is displayed ..

Comment: alert `domainIDS` and `ids`.Check if only selected checkbox ids are getting stored.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran  `https://ibb.co/h1ycRm`

Comment: @JibinBalachandran `https://ibb.co/eeo0e6`

Comment: @JibinBalachandran [output](https://ibb.co/iKtYz6)

Comment: @JibinBalachandran [DoctorID](https://ibb.co/h1ycRm)  Domain based On ID Count: [ModulesID](https://ibb.co/eeo0e6) Module Based on Checked Count value [DropDown](https://ibb.co/iKtYz6)  All dropw down value get without Checkbox

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get what you want to achieve

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Only checked Module Checkbox drop down value is required.

Answer (score 0):

in this code is working for me . anything issues in this code please comment to me

```
var permission = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var item = ids[i];
                var select4 = 'select.' + item;
                permission.push($(select4).find('option:selected').val())
            }

            alert(permission);
```